# Windows 7 PC refuses to join domain

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-7, domain, domain-controller

So, we're wiping clean all PCs at our office and migrating them to a new server cluster and a new domain. Last night I tested on PC and it mostly worked except it refuses to join to the domain.

Now, our domain is named like `EXAMPLE.COM`. When I just type `EXAMPLE` the PC can't find the domain controller, even though I can ping it find. If I type `EXAMPLE.COM` it seems to work. How can I get it to work with just `EXAMPLE`? That's how I got all the new servers int he cluster to work (about 20 of them) and I haven't had any issues...

The only difference between the Windows 7 PC(s) and the servers is that the clients will be on a 10.0.3.X network where as the servers are on a 10.0.1.X network.

Oh, the domain controller and all the other servers are Windows Server 2008 R2.

Suggestions will be highly appreciated!

**UPDATE** per @joeqwerty's request:

The servers network is 10.0.1.X/23. The clients network is 10.0.3.X/24. Both networks are running over their own VPNs on the switches (3x Dell 6224).

The clients are configured to use the DNS of the new domain controller. It also happens to be the one handing out their IPs through DHCP.

The client is complaining that the SRV record for **_ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.EXAMPLE** was not found. Looking at the DNS I can see there is an **_ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.EXAMPLE.COM** under **_msdcs.example.com** forward lookup zone, which is probably the one it's finding.

What do I need to do on the DNS to make it find the non .COM version? Or is that even possible? It should be possible, right?

Comment: Here's a suggestion: Give us some more details. The ip address information is meaningless without the accompanying subnet mask. Assuming though that you're using a /24 subnet mask, what do you have in place to route traffic from one subnet to another? Are the client computers configured to use the new AD/DNS server for DNS? Etc., etc. The more details you give us the better we'll be able to provide informed answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no harm in just typing example.com, but I can understand your desire to know why it's not working the way you expected.

A few more questions:

1) Why are the servers on a 23-bit subnet?

2) VPNs to where and for what?  Or did you mean VLANs?  Do not confuse those; they are very different entities.

3) Is there a compelling reason you've given your internal domain a .COM prefix rather than .LOCAL?  Naming it EXAMPLE.LOCAL will make your DNS infrastructure much easier to manage, and IIRC, is Microsoft's recommendation.

4) Not really a question, but I don't think you're using the term "cluster" correctly... an actual cluster is a logical grouping of two or more identical servers for failover/load balancing purposes.

Comment: +1 for 1,2,4 but I don't really agree with 3, only to the extent that it is easier for a new admin to AD DS to work with .LOCAL

Comment: For 1) I don't really remember anymore, think it had something to do with the DHCP server. 2) you're right, I meant VLANs. 3) I didn't know any better... :( 4) you're also right in that I'm generalizing the word "cluster" to describe my server rack, even though I do have a Hyper-V failover cluster in it. Overall, I was concerned that typing in the .COM version of the domain would cause issues, but I guess that's not really the case since everything has been running smooth for a while now in the month since I asked the question. Thanks for the help though!